# Strange Behavior of Multiprocess Manager Ignoring Rest of Code Block

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am experiencing strange behaviors regarding `Manager`, where the code from the same code block after it's instantiation gets ignored.

I am running this on Windows 10.

When I run only the following code on a separate `test.py` file, everything works fine.
`Manager()` does create it's own proxy process, and all `print()` functions executes. Also, `runIP` process doesn't seem to have any problem.

**test.py**

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from Image_Processing.image_processing import runIP
    from multiprocessing import Manager
    print("TRYING TO CREATE MANAGER")
    manager = Manager()
    print("CREATED MANAGER")
    runIP(manager)
print("ALL DONE!")
```

**output**

```python
TRYING TO CREATE MANAGER
CREATED MANAGER
ALL DONE!
```

However, when I run the same code in `main.py`, where it has codes that import `tensorflow`, it goes weird.

**main.py**

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from Image_Processing.image_processing import runIP
    from multiprocessing import Manager
    print("TRYING TO CREATE MANAGER")
    manager = Manager()
    print("CREATED MANAGER")
    runIP(manager)
print("ALL DONE!")


from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from stable_baselines import DQN
import Reinforcement_AI.env.seperate_env as sep_env
...
```

**output**

```python
TRYING TO CREATE MANAGER
ALL DONE!

# tensorflow import logs printing
```

The second `print()` and `runIP()` does not execute, however, by checking the Task Manager, I did confirm that the proxy process is running. The python interpreter just ignores the rest of the code block for some reason.

I have no clue what's causing this behavior. This is my first time attempting multiprocessing in Python, so I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `Manager` has a problem with `tensorflow`.

To make sure `Manager` is instantiated before doing anything with `tensorflow`,
move every code related to `tensorflow` into a funcion, including the imports.
Then call the funcion in the `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

```
def launchAgent():
    from stable_baselines import DQN
    import Reinforcement_AI.env.seperate_env as sep_env
    from queue import Queue
    from threading import Thread

    #tf related code
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from Image_Processing.image_processing import runIP
    from multiprocessing import Manager

    print("TRYING TO CREATE MANAGER")
    manager = Manager()
    print("CREATED MANAGER")
    runIP(manager)
    launchAgent()
```

This solved my issue.